# mongoose query return empty array if filter has a field name that is camel cased

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

**The following issue was with some code written in express/nodejs.**

I experienced something I could not find any material in regards,
I encountered an issue whereas making a find query with mongoose returned an empty array.
After tinkering I discovered it was due to the key used `(customerRef)` being camel cased
I tried to tweak other fields from and to camelcase and got the same issue.

see example here:

```
        const lastCart = await Cart.findOne({ customerRef: customer._id }, function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('TCL: err', err);
            }
            console.log('TCL: docs', docs); //result = []
        });
```

then went and tweaked my database objects from:

```
{ 
    ....
    "customerRef" : "5dfcd194ca19972b888d66c2", 
    ....
}
```

to:

```
{ 
    ....
    "customerref" : "5dfcd194ca19972b888d66c2", 
    ....
}
```

then the query worked as expected:(customerRef >>> customerref)

```
        const lastCart = await Cart.findOne({ customerref: customer._id }, function(err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('TCL: err', err);
            }
            console.log('TCL: docs', docs); //result is now ok = [...]
        });
```

Now to top this off here's another bit of info:
I use studio 3T for mMongoDB and over there I do not have this issue when making queries.

I would appreciate any and all explanation on this behavior aswell as alternatives if possible.

See my full repo here:
(My skills are novice at best so I apologize in advanced and welcome any feedback)

https://github.com/Darkmift/MEAN-SuperMarket/blob/master/backend/app/controllers/userController.js#L121

Comment: There's nothing special about camel case, the field name likely wasn't the same somewhere in your doc, query, or schema.

Comment: I can assure you its not the case I reproduced this numerous times.

Comment: Can you put together a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: see my above notes.
change a camelcased field in the query and in the object in the collection.
when its camel cased it will return empty and when not camelcased it works fine.

there's also my full repo linked.

Comment: Emphasis on the "minimal" :) Provide a schema, document and query that reproduces the problem.

Comment: apologies @JohnnyHK you were correct from the start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time I have concluded the issue was with my use of the mongo shell program (Studio 3t)

at the time I was not aware how to properly insert an ObjectId.
When using the built in query one must add:

```
{
...
"customerRef" : ObjectId(RefId)
...
}
```

and NOT:

```
{
...
"customerRef" : "RefId"
...
}
```